# Uploading data from an HTML form to Parse.com

Tags: html, post, parse-platform

I want to make a simple HTML webpage and use a form on that page to upload an object to my server on [parse.com](http://parse.com)

For example, if this is my form:

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

Then I assume I would want some kind of `post` request, but I don't know how to set that part up with Parse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this using the REST API at Parse. You should find all the info you need in the guide:

https://www.parse.com/docs/rest

Answer (score -1):

The form should have the following arguments:
`<form action="some_page.php" method="get">`

using `get` will show the sent data from inputs in the url, `post` will hide.

See this tutorial for more information about forms http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Adrew is referring on how to create a simple form that relies on Parse.com Rest API.